# Erro API Tabela FIPE

Tags: javascript, json

Estou utilizando uma API para consumir dados da tabela FIPE para peenchimento de um formulário. Consigo consumir o campo de **Marca** e **Ano**, porém, o campo veículo da erro.

Link da documentação: 
https://deividfortuna.github.io/fipe/

Segue o código:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var urlBase = "https://fipe.parallelum.com.br/api/v1/carros/marcas";
  
/** Marcas**/ 
  
  $.getJSON(urlBase, function(data) {
    var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UMA MARCA</option>"];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      items += ("<option value='" + val.codigo + "'>" + val.nome + "</option>");
    });
    $("#marcas").html(items);
  });
  
  /** Veiculo**/ 
 
  $("#marcas").change(function() {
    $.getJSON(urlBase + "/" + jQuery("#marcas").val() + "/" + "modelos", function(data) {
      var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UM VEICULO</option>"];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items += ("<option value='" + val.codigo + "'>" + val.nome + "</option>");
      });
      $("#modelos").html(items);
    });
  });
  
  /** Ano**/ 
  
  $("#veiculos").change(function() {
    $.getJSON(urlBase + "/" + jQuery("#marcas").val() + "/" + "modelos" + "/" + jQuery("#modelos").val() + "/" + "anos", function(data) {
      var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA O ANO</option>"];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items += ("<option value='" + val.id + "'>" + val.name + "</option>");
      });
      $("#ano").html(items);
    });
  });
});
 </script>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="marcas">
        </select>
  <select id="modelos">
        </select>
  <select id="ano">
        </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Caso alguém consiga me da uma luz, eu serei muito grato. 
Obrigado.

Comment: coloca o código no corpo da pergunta

Comment: Feito! 
Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente esse código:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var urlBase = "//fipe.parallelum.com.br/api/v1/carros/marcas";

      /** Marcas**/

      $.getJSON(urlBase, function(data) {
        var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UMA MARCA</option>"];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          items += ("<option value='" + val.codigo + "'>" + val.nome + "</option>");
        });
        $("#marcas").html(items);
      });

      /** Veiculo**/

      $("#marcas").change(function() {
        $.getJSON(urlBase + "/" + jQuery("#marcas").val() + "/" + "modelos", function(data) {
          var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UM VEICULO</option>"];
          $.each(data.modelos, function(key, val) {
            items += ("<option value='" + val.codigo + "'>" + val.nome + "</option>");
          });
          $("#modelos").html(items);
        });
      });

      /** Ano**/

      $("#modelos").change(function() {
        $.getJSON(urlBase + "/" + jQuery("#marcas").val() + "/" + "modelos" + "/" + jQuery("#modelos").val() + "/" + "anos", function(data) {
          var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA O ANO</option>"];
          $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            console.log(data)
            items += ("<option value='" + val.codigo + "'>" + val.nome + "</option>");
          });
          $("#ano").html(items);
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Documento sem título</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="marcas">
  </select>
  <select id="modelos">
  </select>
  <select id="ano">
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Pontos arrumados:

Foi arrumado que não estava chamando o array;

```
{"modelos":[{"nome":
```

Começa com **modelos**.

Então na hora de chamar, precisa dizer qual array;

```
data.modelos
```

Outra coisa, em `$('#veiculos')` troquei para `$("#modelos").change(function() {`

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muito obrigado mesmo, me salvou :))

Comment: Prestei atenção também onde estava errando, ficou de aprendizado!

Comment: @PhillipFerreira quando tiver problemas, joga um `console.log(data)`, e acesse o link da API também para ver os arrays que ela chama.